How to migrate SharePoint Online list using Sharepoint migration api?
I am working on SharePoint list migration tool. I want to migrate lists with it's content from one SharePoint online site to another. What i thought of using is SharePoint migration api, but the documentation for it is very vague and i can't find many examples of it. I was able to export some metadata with CreateSPAsyncReadJob, but it does not seem like its exporting the list item fields. So the question would be: how can i export list data including the fields and if someone has some working examples of it?
My current code looks something like this. For now only the exporting is working (without the field data). As far as i understand is that for the Migration Job you need to have DataContainer. But how do i build that data container from a SharePoint online list?
        ClientContext sourceContext = authenticationManager.GetWebLoginClientContext(siteUrl, null);

        var listUrl = $"{siteUrl}/Lists/Data";
        
        ClientResult<ProvisionedMigrationContainersInfo> containers = sourceContext.Site.ProvisionMigrationContainers();
        sourceContext.ExecuteQuery();

        ClientResult<ProvisionedMigrationQueueInfo> queue = sourceContext.Site.ProvisionMigrationQueue();
        sourceContext.ExecuteQuery();

        var encryptOption = new EncryptionOption
        {
            AES256CBCKey = containers?.Value.EncryptionKey,
        };

        var output = sourceContext.Site.CreateSPAsyncReadJob(
            listUrl,
            new AsyncReadOptions
            {
                IncludeDirectDescendantsOnly = true,
                IncludeSecurity = true,
            },
            encryptOption,
            containers.Value.MetadataContainerUri,
            queue.Value.JobQueueUri);
        sourceContext.ExecuteQuery();

        ClientResult<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.MigrationJobState> exportJobState = sourceContext.Site.GetMigrationJobStatus(output.Value.JobId);
        do
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            exportJobState = sourceContext.Site.GetMigrationJobStatus(output.Value.JobId);
            sourceContext.ExecuteQuery();
        } while (exportJobState.Value == Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.MigrationJobState.Queued || exportJobState.Value == Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.MigrationJobState.Processing);

        ClientContext targetContext = authenticationManager.GetWebLoginClientContext(targetSiteUrl, null);

        targetContext.Load(targetContext.Web);
        targetContext.ExecuteQuery();

        var migrationJobId = targetContext.Site.CreateMigrationJobEncrypted(
          targetContext.Web.Id,
          containers.Value.DataContainerUri,
          containers.Value.MetadataContainerUri,
          queue.Value.JobQueueUri,
        encryptOption);

        targetContext.ExecuteQuery();

        ClientResult<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.MigrationJobState> importJobState = sourceContext.Site.GetMigrationJobStatus(migrationJobId.Value);
        do
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            importJobState = sourceContext.Site.GetMigrationJobStatus(migrationJobId.Value);
            targetContext.ExecuteQuery();
        } while (importJobState.Value == Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.MigrationJobState.Queued || importJobState.Value == Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.MigrationJobState.Processing);

